# How To pre-select value in Listview SingleChoice?

Tags: android, listview

How to Preselect value in ListView Single Choice? Actually I am creating app where user have to select his work type like farmer etc.

And in my database user selected farmer now through this listview I am giving him to choice to change is type so that's why I have to show first what he selected first.

Here is my code.

```
public class UserTypeSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<UserTypePrivacySettings> userTypePrivacySettingsList;
private ListView userTypeListView;
private int listpos;


public int getListpos() {
    return listpos;
}

public void setListpos(int listpos) {
    this.listpos = listpos;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_type_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setActionbar();
    initViews();


}

private void initViews() {
    userTypeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userTypeListView);
    userTypeListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    userTypePrivacySettingsList = new Parse(UserTypeSettings.this).parseUserType();

    userTypeListView.setAdapter(new SingleChoiceArrayadapter(this, userTypePrivacySettingsList) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            setListpos(position);

            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    });

   userTypeListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });
    userTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("check user stype", userTypePrivacySettingsList.get(position).getUser_type());
        }

    });
}}
```

Here is my adapter class

```
public class SingleChoiceArrayadapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserTypePrivacySettings> {
    public SingleChoiceArrayadapter(Context context, List<UserTypePrivacySettings> usertypes) {
        super(context, 0, usertypes);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, parent, false);
        }


        UserTypePrivacySettings user = getItem(position);
        final CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        textView.setText(user.getUser_type());
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kisanColorGreen));



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getUser_type().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I set a pre-selected item on a Simple Adapter. But it should work the same as you have it now. If not let me know.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);


int selectedPosition;

userTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }
});

userTypeListView.performItemClick(userTypeListView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, position);
```

Comment: actually sir can you tell me how to get position  of our list item ?